# Break commands into new line in Dos command

Tags: ms-dos, notepad

I am trying to copy a few commands into DOS from a notepad file, and when I copy them I want them to be on new lines for each command.

**Input:** `cd..  mkdir 568  cd 568`

When I copy this into DOS I want something like

```
cd.. 
mkdir 568  
cd 568
```

I tried `cd.. ^ mkdir 568 ^ cd 568` using different characters but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

You were right the Carat is useless in the situation of putting multiple commands on One single line, for the purpose of processing them one after the other.
I tested many of the methods and finnaly found the one that best works in your example above.  **&**  or **&&**

> CLS && H: && CD\ && CD "new folder" && MKDIR stuff && CD stuff

H: is my target drive
One fail on the line, and the rest of the items on the line will not process (see &).
Mine has some more kludgy things in it so It would repeat.

That ^ worked the same way as this (below) does, except in a fail that bails out.

```
CLS
H:
CD\
CD "new folder"
MKDIR stuff
CD Stuff
```

This ^ can also be pasted into the CMDprompt for windows 7 and works fine.

---

The conditional processing symbols for issueing multiple commands from the same
prompt and to act based on the results of a command.

The ampersand (&) separates multiple commands on one command line.
The parentheses groups multiple commands.
The semicolon or comma (; ,) separate command parameters.
The caret (^) cancels a subsequent command symbol's special meaning so you can
use a command symbol as text.
The double ampersand (&&) causes the command following this symbol to run only
if the command preceding the symbol is successful.
The double pipe (||) causes the command following this symbol to run only if the
command preceding the symbol fails.